# Include assembly file in another assembly file

Tags: gcc, assembly, include

I have two files, main.s and test.s where test.s looks like this:

```
test:
   add a1,a2,a2
```

...and main.s looks like this:

```
main:
   call test
```

(very senseless examples). How can I include test in main? I am using gcc like this:

> gcc -o main main.c

But I have no idea how I can use test in there...any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can include the file just as you would with anything else in GCC:

```
 #include"test.S"
```

Were you using NASM you would use:

```
 %include "test.s"
```

Comment: As far as I know GCC treats the file extensions ".s" (lowercase) and ".S" (uppercase) differently: Uppercase allows pre-processor directives (such as #include or #ifdef), lowercase not. Under Windows this is just a difference in the command line of GCC because the file names themselfes are case-insensitive. Under Linux the file must be (re-)named the correct way.